# Deployment - code coverage issue

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I came across this question on a blog and am not sure what will be the correct answer to this?

A developer creates a new Visualforce page and Apex extension, and writes test classes that exercise 95% coverage of the new Apex extension.
Change set deployment to production fails with the test coverage warning: "Average test coverage across all Apex classes and triggers is 74%, at least 75% test coverage is required."
What can the developer do to successfully deploy the new Visualforce page and extension?

A. Create test classes to exercise the Visualforce page markup.

B. Select "Disable Parallel Apex Testing" to run all the tests.

C. Add test methods to existing test classes from previous deployments.

D. Select "Fast Deployment'' to bypass running all the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is C.

It seems a bit odd, because you would think production would already be over 75%. But production tests can break when things are added such as validation rules, changing fields to required, etc. So tests that were passing on production now may fail because the test coverage that is there is no longer correct.

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes complete sense. At some places I saw D as the answer and it didn't seem right to me.

Comment: @AnumGoel-BackOffice please mark as answered, thanks.